# Python Pandas Merge Won't Work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two Python Pandas DataFrames:

`Inventory_Info` (20 rows):

```
Group, Facility, Unit, Room, HardwareAddress
'Generic Hospital Group', 'Generic Hospital', 'Generic Hospital Ward', 'Generic Hospital Room', 5715
```

`Data` (47 rows):

```
Serial_Number, Last_Server_Check, Num_Check_Ins, HardwareAddress
00BA0F42, 23, 1/18/17 20:38, 3906
```

All 20 values of `Inventory_Info.HardwareAddress` appear in `Data.HardwareAddress`.

I've tried this, but it doesn't merge the data. I get column names from both DataFrames, but only the contents of `Data` are included.

```
finalDataSet = pandas.DataFrame.merge(Data, Inventory_Info, how='left', on='HardwareAddress')
```

Similarly, I've tried flipping the DataFrame order:

```
finalDataSet = pandas.DataFrame.merge(Inventory_Info, Data, how='left', on='HardwareAddress')
```

I get the merged column names, but now only the `Inventory_Info` data is displayed.

I've tried using this merge syntax:

```
finalDataSet = webData.merge(rawData, left_index='HardwareAddress', right_on='HardwareAddress')
```

While this syntax gets the data into the correct format and populates all columns, the data is not matched on the `HardwareAddress` index and its arrangement is wrong.

Comment: First, you need to post the head of each DataFrame. Next, alias pandas as `pd`. Finally, do not use pandas.DataFrame.merge. Use `pd.merge`.

Comment: I tried pd.merge just now and got the same results as pd.DataFrame.merge.

Comment: please edit your question and paste the results of `print(Data.head())` and `print(Inventory_Info.head())`

Comment: *All 20 values of Inventory_Info.HardwareAddress appearin Data.HardwareAddress*...without data we can't reproduce and can only take your word for it. Also *I get column names from both DataFrames, but only the contents of Data are included.*...do you mean NaNs return? Do note you are using `left` join so non-matches do return NaNs.

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved this one.

`Inventory_Info.dtypes` and `Data.dtypes` each revealed that `HardwareAddress` was type `object`. I used `Data['HardwareAddress'].astype(int)` and `Inventory_Info['HardwareAddress'].astype(int)`, and then the DataFrames merged exactly as expected.

Comment: This lead me to ----> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898826/converting-object-column-in-pandas-dataframe-to-datetime I had a similar issue, but with date.

Comment: Looks like I could have used: `.astype('datetime64')`