# Converting object column in pandas dataframe to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have an object column in a pandas dataframe in the format dd/mm/yyyy, that I want to convert with to_datetime.

I tried to convert it to datetime using the below:

```
df['Time stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time stamp'], format= '%d/%m/%Y')
```

I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Does this mean that there is a blank row somewhere, I have checked the original csv and I cannot see one.

Comment: It might be because of the formatting of your data. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583256/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime-ii

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means you have an extra space. Though `pd.to_datetime` is very good at parsing dates normally without any format specified, when you actually specify a format, it has to match EXACTLY.

You can likely solve your issue by adding `.str.strip()` to remove the extra whitespace before converting.

```
import pandas as pd
df['Time stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time stamp'].str.strip(), format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Alternatively, you can take advantage of its ability to parse various formats of dates by using the `dayfirst=True` argument

```
df['Time stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time stamp'], dayfirst=True)
```

---

#### Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time stamp': ['01/02/1988', '01/02/1988 ']})

pd.to_datetime(df['Time stamp'], format= '%d/%m/%Y')
```

> ValueError: unconverted data remains:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Time stamp'].str.strip(), format='%d/%m/%Y')
#0   1988-02-01
#1   1988-02-01
#Name: Time stamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]

pd.to_datetime(df['Time stamp'], dayfirst=True)
#0   1988-02-01
#1   1988-02-01
#Name: Time stamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```